# Bad CPU type in executable after migrating to new Macbook

Tags: homebrew

I just got a new Macbook and did the migration from my old one. It looks like the homebrew executables have a bad CPU type and don't work. Things are a bit stuck right now and I'm not sure how to move forward.

Even my `ls` is mapped to `lsd` and I can't list files.

Do I have to manually uninstall brew and related executables by deletion and start over?

[image]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408375/zsh-bad-cpu-type-in-executable perhaps?

Comment: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` did make these work again, but I guess all of these are just the wrong executables now. I suppose brew will install the right CPU info moving forward?

Comment: No idea about that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: I didn't test this myself.

If you don't want to alwasy use Rosetta2, you have to manually remove the Intel version of Homebrew, then install the M1 version.

You can save the list of your Intel installed package with:

```
brew list > myHomebrewPackages.txt
```

You will then have to reinstall them on the M1 version.

To remove the Intel version, download the uninstall script from [the official Homebrew github repository](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh). Make it executable with:

```
chmod +x uninstall.sh
```

and run it with:

```
./uninstall.sh --path=/usr/local
```

Then install the M1 version with:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

The M1 version of Homebrew will be installed under `/opt/homebrew`.

Comment: How do you install all the packages saved in `myHomebrewPackages.txt` once you reinstall the M1 Homebrew?

Comment: @AlejandroGarcíaIglesias The quickest way is to use `brew bundle`. See my answer ↓ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue. Following steps helped to resolved the issue for me.

1. Open the terminal
2. Go to Terminal -> Settings...
3. Change the profile to Homebrew
4. Close the terminal and open again

[image: Change from Basic to Homebrew profile]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. I tried everything but in the end had to uninstall homebrew (which deleted all my packages) and install it again.

##### Reinstalling all your packages

If you still have access to the old computer you can create a list of your installed packages (saved as a file named **Brewfile**)... 
`brew bundle dump`

Copy that Brewfile onto your new machine, and in that same folder on the new machine do... 
`brew bundle`

That should install all your packages (and their dependencies).

To see all your packages (without confusing dependencies mixed in): 
`brew leaves | xargs brew desc --eval-all`

*NOTE: You might not get the same package versions on the new machine, since homebrew is a [rolling release](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle?tab=readme-ov-file#versions-and-lockfiles) package manager. It doesn't let you install old versions of a package.*